# Saving group result in celery: AttibuteError

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to save a group result for later retrieval:

```
job = group([
    add.s(1, 1),
    add.s(2, 2)
])
result = job.apply_async()
result.save()

from celery.result import GroupResult
saved_result = GroupResult.restore(result.id)
```

however, I get the error:

```
*** AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_restore_group'
```

I have the backend `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'` set in my config.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you reloaded celery after changes?

Comment: Yeah, I have reloaded celery after all my changes.

Comment: Tested [this code](http://pastebin.com/sDH5wN0p) here and works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to restore using your celery app object.

to use "Getting started with celery" in the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application) as a staring point:

tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

your code:

```
job = group([
    add.s(1, 1),
    add.s(2, 2)
])
result = job.apply_async()
result.save()
return result.id
```

elsewhere:

```
from my.app.tasks import app

result = app.GroupResult.restore(some_id)
```

you example shows you running `restore` in the same context as the `apply_async` - I'm assuming that's a simplificaiton and that you know you don't need to use `restore` unless you are in a different process or if for some reason you can't pass the result object to the new context.